# Based on Radio button selection how to change drop choices in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

I have a radio button and a dropdown where options of radio button: [Employee, Student].
How to change the values accordingly based on radio button selection.
Onclick of Employee the drop down choices should be as[emp1,emp2,emp2]
onclick of student the drop down choices should be as[stu1,stu2,stu2]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the item of the dropdown to:

```
Switch(radioButton.Selected.Value,"Employee",["emp1","emp2"],"Student",["stu1","stu2"]...)
```

Comment: Have one more question, if we want to dynamically popuplate from API data in drop down , what approch i have to follow.